# Symfony2 Form Handling

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony

I am using forms to process my entity data via ajax to an api-method.

My Type Class:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('basicdata', 'form', array('virtual' => true))
        ->add('firstname', null, array('required' => true))
        ->add('lastname', null, array('required' => true))
    );        
    $builder->add('contactdetails', new ContactdetailsType());
    $builder->add('medialinks', new MedialinksType());
}
```

As u can see i seperate my form in 3 sections, one with basedata and 2 additional entities to keep contactdetails and medialinks.

In my JavaScript i have the following listener on the create button:

```
$('#player_form_create').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: remotePathPlayerCreate,
        data: $('.form').serialize()
    });
});
```

According to chromes developer tool the POST data look like following:

```
player_form[basicdata][firstname]:Harvey
player_form[basicdata][lastname]:Specter
player_form[contactdetails][email]:h.specter@pearson.com
player_form[medialinks][website]: http://
```

In my API action i wanna handle the request and save a new player record:

```
public function cpostAction()
{
  $player = new Player();
  $form = $this->createForm(new PlayersType(), $player);
  $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
  if($form->isValid()){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($player);
    $em->persist($player->getContactdetails());
    $em->persist($player->getMedialinks());
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectView(
      $this->generateUrl(
        'get_player',
        array('id' => $player->getId())
      ),
      Codes::HTTP_CREATED
    );
  }

  return array(
    'processedForm' => $form
  );
}
```

As u might allready know, the problem happens while i want to handle the request. I guess `$this->getRequest()` does not contain the POST data information in the format needed by the request handler.

When i post data like this, i get a 500 with `Expected argument of type \"Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request\", \"array\" given`.

How can i achieve that my POST data is submited as an request object?

Comment: comeon, there have to be a best practice for that usecase. i guess im not the only one who wants to submit a form via ajax and take advantage of the form framework.

Comment: when i return `$form` from my method all i get is `{"children":{"basicdata":{"children":{"firstname":[],"lastname":[],....`

Comment: i have found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22348887/1754242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution: According to the page [How to use the submit() Function to handle Form Submissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html) i now use `$form->submit` to submit my array-data to the form:

```
  $form->submit($this->getRequest()->request->get($form->getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when building an app with Symfony on server side and AngularJS on client side. Handling the form this way worked:

```
$content = $this->get('request')->getContent();
if (!empty($content)) { $params = json_decode($content, true); }
else { // return an error or whatever }

$defaultOptions = array('csrf_protection' => false);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, $defaultOptions)
    ->add('email', 'email', array(
        'constraints' => new Constraints\Email(array('message' => 'emailError'))
    ))
    ->getForm();

$form->submit($params);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

Of course here I'm not using a type to create the form like you but the result is the same. This assumes that the request payload is something like this:

```
{email: 'test@example.com'}
```

Comment: My payload look like this player_form[basicdata][firstname]=Harvey&player_form[basicdata][lastname]=Specter

So json_decode doesnot work on $content.

And, can u explain me why u do $form->submit($params) ? Is it that the request data is bind to the form?